# Application Server Jobs or Database Jobs?

Tags: java, oracle11g, weblogic, jobs

In my java-based application, I need a job to read data from a set of tables and insert them into another table. In my first design, I created a oracle job and scheduled it to do the process frequently. 
Unfortunately, when the job fails, there is not enough info available about the root causes of the failure. In addition. deploying the system for many system instances has made the work harder. 
As an alternative work, I am trying to move the job into my application server, as a Weblogic job. Is this a good design or not?

Comment: 'It depends'. You've already run into some issues with your existing approach. Its not to say you won't have issues in a different approach. For example, while reading/writting the data through your application server, are you then consuming CPU cycles that could be better used elsewhere (eg. Customer Facing processes).

Comment: @radimpe: you are right. What do you suggest?

Comment: I've used them both at times. As a 'non-database developer' I am biased towards moving things into the Application but the focus then absolutely has to be on the separation of concerns. For example, if you run a website, you should not let a scheduled job to 'archive orders' interfere with the normal operation of a user trying to purchase something. Depending on your available resources this can be tricky. I can say that I also found the database jobs frustratingly difficult to debug - another reason why I like the application option, though the database one has its place.

Comment: I would also recommend using application layer. As radimpe mentioned, its easy to debug the application than the database. Using application, you may use threading(assuming you have multiple CPUs) to process it parallely making it faster.

Comment: >> Unfortunately, when the job fails, there is not enough info available about the root causes of the failure.  

This complaint is not really related to the fact that it is a database job.  You need to write the database code ( PL/SQL ? ) to log all aspects of the job cycle - start, end, rows processed and errors.  

I also think that there is nothing inherently easier creating a job in Weblogic.  Creating the database job is just a sequence of SQL commands that can be put into a single file.  Can you create a Weblogic job that easily?

Comment: @RMANExpress: In fact no. Writing an application job is not as easy as writing a DB job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having moved my jobs into application server, I have faced the following advantages:

1. Tracking the job failure is easier.
2. Non-DBA users can easily read the application Server logs and fix the issues. (Many users do not have access to DB in production line. )
3. The logic of the job has been moved from my data access layer into my business logic layer and it is more acceptable due to design patterns.